# Is there some safe PS2 Emulator for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, emulation

I want to emulate a PS2 in Ubuntu, I've seen there is an emulator, called PCSX2, but it's not in the Software Centre, so I don't know if it's safe or if there is another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wine to emulate windows programs, there is also this thread which might help:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2021581